# Azure - Web API / App Service Plan - Performance Details not recorded

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans

I have an app service plan which is hosting 2 Web APIs, the issue I am facing is that I am unable to view details such as: CPU Usage, Memory Percentage, Requests, Average Response time etc.

These can be found under the Overview tab for both App Service and App Service Plan but no data is being recorded, even if I retrieve data for the whole week rather than the last hour only.

I have also confirmed that I am hitting the correct App hosted on the correct Plan. Have I missed anything? Do I need to enable something?

I have also generated around 20k requests in the last few hours so I expect something to show up.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's weird. Could you go to `Portal >Monitor > Metrics` and Select your App resource to check if you can see the metrics here.

Comment: @Wayne, Nothing seemed to worked. I even created a new Web APP and try testing it by just refreshing the default page and even that failed. I ended up deleting and re deploying everything, thankfully this is a dev environment.